# Does clock_t calculate the time of all threads, c++, pthreads?

Tags: c++, benchmarking

Lets say my code is made of main() and in main I call 2 threads that run in parallel.

lets say that main takes 5 seconds to finish, and each thread takes 10 seconds to finish.

if I time the main program using clock_t, assuming  the 2 threads run in parallel, the real time that the program will take is 15 seconds.

Now if I time it using clock_t, will that give me a time of 15 seconds or 25 seconds?

Although thread 1 and thread 2 ran in parallel, will the clock_t() calculate every cycle used by thread 1 and thread 2 and return the total number of cycles used?

I use windows mingw32, and pthreads.

example code:

```
main(){
 clock_t begin_time ;

  for (unsigned int id = 0; id < 2; ++id)
  {
     pthread_create(&(threads[id]), NULL, thread_func, (void *) &(data[id]));
  }


  for (unsigned int id = 0; id < 2; ++id)
  {
      pthread_join(threads[id], NULL);
  }

time = double( clock () - begin_time )/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

Comment: When is which thread joined? Before or after the clock stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `clock` does different things in different implementations (in particular, in different OS's). The [`clock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scty34yt.aspx) function in Windows gives the number of clock-ticks from when your program started, regardless of number of threads, and regardless of whether the machine is busy or not [I believe this design decision stems from the ancient days when DOS and Windows 2.x was the fashionable things to use, and the OS didn't have a way of "not running" something].

In Linux, it gives the CPU-time used, as is the case in all Unix-like operating systems, as far as I'm aware.

Edit to clarify: My Linux system says this:

> In  glibc 2.17 and earlier, clock() was implemented on top of times(2).
>   For improved precision, since glibc 2.18, it is implemented on  top  of
>   clock_gettime(2) (using the CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID clock).

In other words, the time is for the process, not for the current thread.

To get the actual CPU-time used by your process if you are using Windows, you can (and should) use [`GetProcessTimes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: From the definition on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/ I cannot see any mention that "loop for 1 second" and "sleep for 1 second" should yield different results. They say "constant units of time since program start" and not a word about processor times.

Comment: On Linux, at least, if memory serves, it gives the number of ticks given to each thread of execution.

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft clearly didn't read that before deciding what their `clock` implementation. It's very clear in the link I posted above.,

Comment: @Tive: See my edit. It gives the process time (or the docs is wrong! :) )

Comment: @Mats Petersson: I saw your edit. The bit about glibc 2.18 now using clock_gettime was interesting since the docs at cppreference.com explain that clock_gettime with CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID gives a better resolution than clock (for POSIX systems).  However, I'm not sure that this helps the OP, since I have no idea if pthreads as implemented on Windows for MinGW has chosen to adhere to POSIX or to the behavior of the underlying OS or not.  Perhaps in this case it's best to use chrono (if available) since that always defaults to wall-clock time...

Comment: Like I said, and have now clarified, is that the `GetProcessTimes` call in Windows is the RIGHT solution for getting the total time of the process in Windows. If using another OS, `clock` may be OK. And yes, `clock_gettime`.

Comment: ``clock()`` on freebsd also seems to return CPU time (not real time), so my little test program postulates. I kinda like how win32 function names are so much more expressive than that usual c-api/posix/unistd whatnot stuff. :) Just imagine the wall CLOCK in your workplace only showed productive hours...

Comment: You were right. I tried it using a dummy code and indeed, it measures wall clock.

Comment: @BitTickler: Such a clock would be rather slow at times in my case... :)

Comment: @user304584: I'm not the one being right, it's the Windows documentation that is right - I just happen to have seen this a few times before...